# Null distribution of sign bias test for GARCH

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, garch

I just read the paper of [Engle & Ng (1993)](http://finance.martinsewell.com/stylized-facts/volatility/EngleNg1993.pdf) in which they introduced the sign bias test (positive sign bias t., negative sign bias t., joint test). I have a problem understanding what the test statistic is.
Is it $\chi^2$ with 3 DF for the joint and 1 DF for the other tests?

Reference:

- Engle, Robert F., and Victor K. Ng. ["Measuring and testing the impact of news on volatility."](http://finance.martinsewell.com/stylized-facts/volatility/EngleNg1993.pdf) *The Journal of Finance* 48.5 (1993): 1749-1778.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P. 1759-1760 of the paper give answers to your questions.

P. 1759:

> The LM test statistic is asymptotically distributed as chi-square with $m$ degrees of freedom when the null hypothesis is true, where $m$ is the number of parameter restrictions.

See equations (9a)-(9c) to find that the number of parameter restrictions is 1 for sign bias, negative sign bias and  positive sign bias test.

Also, p. 1760 reads explicitly about the joint test:

> In particular, the LM statistic follows a chi-square distribution with 3 degrees of freedom.

(See equation 10.)